# Printing out 178-character string in 270 characters of brainf*ck

Tags: string, security, encryption, hash, brainfuck

I’m trying to print out a 178-character string in brainfuck. This wouldn’t be a problem except I’m limited to using 270 characters of brainfuck. I was thinking of hashing the 178-character string using a two-way hashing function, but I've been having trouble finding a solution that works. Here is the string: `"Wikipedia is the best thing ever. Anyone in the world can write anything they want about any subject, so you know you are getting the best possible information." - Michael Scott`.

Running the string straight-up in some ascii->brainfuck programs is giving me about 1,409 characters, far off from my target of 270. I think I should be able to create the brainfuck code with a string of about 60 characters. So my question is, is there any way to convert the above string to a string of 60 characters that can later be decoded back to the string?

Comment: I would ask "what have you tried" but I'm afraid you would answer :)

Comment: I've tried a number of two-way hashing functions, but none of them have been short enough (~60 characters). One-way hashing functions won't work because they can't be decompressed.

Comment: Are you intending to do the two-way hashing *in Brainfuck*? If so, I can pretty much guarantee you that it won't be less than 270 characters.

Comment: already you're limited to 178 characters of `.` So this means you have to to organize the remaining 92 characters in the most efficient manner possible to type your message.

Comment: @Jouster500 Not necessarily. If you manage to write the desired string onto the tape, you can print all of it with `[.>]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's most probably impossible. Brainfuck isn't magic. The current record for shortest code to print the 13-char string "Hello, World!" is an entire [78 bytes.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494/31957):

```
--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+.
```

I suggest you read the post, but a TL;DR for you is that the tape is first initialized with a recurrence relation, then poke around the tape to print the appropriate characters.

78 bytes for *thirteen characters*. On a relatively simple string. That's 6 bytes for each character. Using the same metric as a rough guide (and this result is an underestimate), your string would take 1068 characters--at a minimum. Given that, however, the tape initialization occurs only once, and this can be surprisingly small, you may (may) be able to get it down to the high 900 or 800s. Your string also happens to be more complex and differ very widely in ASCII values, something even a recurrence relation is unlikely to solve. I however have no example that small.